# Nginx Reverse Proxy Help Streaming MP4 File

Tags: nginx, proxy

I want to use my Nginx server as a reverse proxy for streaming static .mp4 files.

The following configuration works like a charm:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  location = /video.mp4 {
  proxy_pass http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_5mb.mp4;
}
}
```

However, when I try with a different URL that has a redirection, it doesnt work

```
server {
listen 80;
location = /video.mp4 {
proxy_pass https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/LAT5gl_qqSy7Ey7eg_mzBAMzCpYPKtYzqcpfmomBowby0PNuHhKNAZ-A9fqYPi0hlOrrJpVjCFymsp780A=m22;
}
}
```

However, the googleusercontent link works when I access it directly via web browser .

Any help ? Thanks